# OpenMP: multiple reductions in parallel

Tags: c++, concurrency, openmp, c++20

I have some code that looks like this:

```
double r1 = 0.0, r2 = 0.0;

for (size_t i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
    r1 += reduction1(data1[i]);
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
    r2 += reduction2(data2[i]);
}
```

The two reductions, while they run over the same number of iterations, otherwise run on different paths and on different sets of data. I was wondering whether there is a way to run both reductions in parallel.

Bonus: what if the two loops ran for different number of iterations?

Edit: in my case `k` is fairly small, and most of the work is done inside the individual `reduction` functions. So my goal is to parallelize as many executions of reduction functions as possible.

Comment: *in my case k is fairly small, and most of the work is done inside the individual reduction functions* which suggests that perhaps it is the `reduction` function itself which ought to be parallelised?

Comment: Do you mean you got 25% speedup compared to serial version?

Comment: @Laci Yes exactly.

Comment: Well, 25% is extremely underwhelming. As @JeromeRichard wrote "Without profiling and more infos, it is hard to tell what is the best solution. ". Alternatively if you can provide a [mre] we can check it.

Answer (score 5):

If you can use one loop it is very easy:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:r1,r2)
for (size_t i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
    r1 += reduction1(data1[i]);
    r2 += reduction2(data2[i]);
}
```

if not, use tasks/taskloop:

```
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp single
{
    #pragma omp taskloop reduction(+:r1)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        r1 += reduction1(data1[i]);
    }

    #pragma omp taskloop reduction(+:r2)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        r2 += reduction2(data1[i]);
    }

}
```

EDIT: You mentioned in the comments that `k` is small, so probably the best is to use a separate task for each `reduction1/reduction2` calculation. Also @JeromeRichard pointed out that in the case of using `taskloop` the second loop will wait for all the previous tasks of the first loop to be completed. So, based on these new information, a better alternative may be something like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp single
{
#pragma omp taskgroup task_reduction(+:r1,r2)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        #pragma omp task in_reduction(+:r1)
        {
            r1 += reduction1(data1[i]);
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        #pragma omp task in_reduction(+:r2)
        {
            r2 += reduction2(data2[i]);
        }   
    }
}

}
```

You also mentioned in the comments that the parallel code is only 25% faster than the serial one, which suggests a major problem, which should be investigated by profiling your program.

Comment: You win. My bad. Sorry for trolling. Have an upvote!

Comment: In your first example, aren't the two reductions (within each iteration of the loop) run serially?

Comment: Within a single iteration yes, but who cares if `k` is big enough. ps: How big is `k`?

Comment: `k` is fairly small, the reductions are the heavy part unfortunately.

Comment: Your first example takes about the same time as parallelizing the loops independently. The second example seems to be a bit slower in my tests :(

Comment: In this case, you shoud try  `nowait` clause after the first parallel loop... ps: I do not claim that either of the solutions will be faster on your computer, just that  reduction1/reduction2 is "more parallel".

Comment: A `nowait` is indeed a good idea in the second case as the second loop will wait for all the previous tasks of the first loop to be completed. Besides, I think it is important to note that the scheduling of a `taskloop` region will be different from a basic one. Tasks are often detrimental on NUMA systems because of this (unfortunately). Taskloop can a also a bit slower on many-core systems. An alternative solution is to create 2 tasks where each compute a serial or parallel reduction. Without profiling and more infos, it is hard to tell what is the best solution.

Comment: `nowait` doesn't seem to be valid for `taskloop`..

Comment: OK, I have removed it

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
double r1 = 0.0, r2 = 0.0;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:r1,r2)
for (size_t i = 0; i < k1+k2; ++i) {
    if (i < k1) {
        r1 += reduction1(data1[i]);
    } else {
        r2 += reduction2(data2[i-k1]);
    }
}
```

The two original loops don't even need to have the same number of iterations. If the work inside the `reduction?()` routines is unbalanced between iterations, a `schedule(dynamic,1)` clause may also help.

EDIT. Or (but not sure for this one):

```
double r1 = 0.0, r2 = 0.0;

#pragma omp parallel reduction(+:r1,r2)
{
    #pragma omp for nowait schedule(dynamic,1)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < k1; ++i) {
        r1 += reduction1(data1[i]);
    }
    #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic,1)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < k2; ++i) {
        r2 += reduction2(data2[i]);
    }
}
```